How to fix Console Error "CSS Stylesheet not loaded due to 'text/html' MIME mismatch" in Django 4.2?
I was just working on my website, and everyday the grand stylings worked fine and everything was up to good shape. But today, I went on Chrome and loaded my website first offline using the Django default server and it showed no styles, and I thought that it was just a WIFI issue. Once I connected, I saw the stylings didn't change and there are 2 MIME errors in my consoles for all the 3 browsers I tried it with (Microsoft Edge, Firefox, and Chrome). My static directories are setup properly, but for some reason when I tried to visit the stylesheet link to get a CSS file, I got 404 instead. I really don't know why this is happening.
I tried doing some simple changes to my stylesheet, like removing any comments, and I even removed the rel='stylesheet' attribute to see what happened. Nothing worked. I went and did many Google searches, and even used the AI preview there, browsed through Stack Overflow, and read the documentation. I tried all their recommendations but nothing worked. Here is the code snippet for my  tags and static setup in settings.py.
<!-- HTML HEAD -->
  <head>
    {% block ex_head %} {% endblock %}
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <link
      type="text/css"
      href="{% static 'stylesheets/main.css' %}"
      
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/static/logo.png" />
    <title>Website Title</title>
    {% load static %}
    <script src="{% static 'blockly.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'p5.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'blockly_compressed.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'blocks_compressed.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'python_compressed.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'en.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'p5.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'p5.dom.js' %}"></script>
    {% load bootstrap5 %} {% bootstrap_css %} {% bootstrap_javascript %}
    <style>
      body {
        font-family: "DefaultFont";
      }
      .margins {
        margin-left: 15px;
      }
      .margins-top {
        margin-top: 10px;
      }
      #blocklyDiv {
        height: 480px;
        width: 600px;
        background-color: aqua;
        position: absolute;
        top: 12%;
        margin-left: 15px;
      }
      #canvasDiv {
        height: 480px;
        width: 600px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 60%;
        color: black;
        border: 1px red ridge;
      }
    
    </style>
  
    {% block extra_style %} {% endblock %}
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    
  </head>

# Settings.py Static Setup
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static"
]

If you need more code snippets, just ask for one via comment.

Do you still get the error if you remove type="text/css" but keep the rel="stylesheet"?

Hi. Sorry to respond late, but yes, even if I remove type='text/css' and keep the rel='stylehseet' nothing changes.

I tried changing the static settings one time. It worked for one day, and now it is not working again.

I found a temporary solution for development of using DEBUG = True instead of False.

When using DEBUG = False you should run python manage.py collectstatic for your static files (css, js) to work.

I got this error message when I did exactly what you said: django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: You're using the staticfiles app without having set the STATIC_ROOT setting to a filesystem path.
